# Making an XML layout programmatically not working

Tags: android, xml

I wanted to re-create my XML layout programatically, but it doesn't seem to work. I found out how to (supposedly) create it programatically from another thread. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

The XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white">



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test1"
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:paddingTop = "36dp"
        android:paddingRight = "36dp"
        android:paddingLeft = "18dp"
        android:paddingBottom = "36dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txt1"
        android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:paddingTop = "36dp"
        android:paddingRight = "36dp"
        android:paddingBottom = "36dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code I'm attempting to match the XML above:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // Creating a new RelativeLayout
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    // Defining the RelativeLayout layout parameters.
    // In this case I want to fill its parent



    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);


    // Creating a new TextView
    TextView txt1 = new TextView(this);
    txt1.setText("Test1");

    TextView txt2 = new TextView(this);
    txt2.setText("Test2");

    // Defining the layout parameters of the TextView
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, txt1.getId());

    txt1.setPadding(18,36,36,36);
    txt2.setPadding(0,36,36,36);

    // Setting the parameters on the TextView
    txt1.setLayoutParams(lp);
    txt2.setLayoutParams(lp2);

    // Adding the TextView to the RelativeLayout as a child
    relativeLayout.addView(txt1);
    relativeLayout.addView(txt2);

    // Setting the RelativeLayout as our content view
    setContentView(relativeLayout, rlp);


}
```

}

[What I see when I run it programmatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxTm1.png)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"? Can you not see it at all? Are the `View`s just misaligned?

Comment: Added a picture

Comment: The `addRule()` call you have on `lp2` is not doing anything because `txt1` doesn't have an ID until you assign it one. (Technically, it has ID -1, but that's ignored, as it's `View.NO_ID`.)

Comment: Oh so all I had to do was add:        
txt1.setId(R.id.txt1);      Thanks!